# splitting a string into similar elements along with the values

Tags: parsing

I have a string like

```
$query = "date=20.10.2007&amount=400+date=11.02.2008&amount=1400+date=12.03.2008&amount=1500";
```

there are two variables named date and amount containing a value e.g date= 20.10.2007 and amount=400 and these two variables repeat itself with different values and each set (date & amount) are separated by '+' sign. Now i want to display this string like this:

```
   Date      Amount
20.10.2007   400
11.02.2008   1400
12.02.2008   1500
```

Need help

Comment: What programming language/tool are you using here?

Comment: php programming language

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can make judicious use of `explode` and `preg_split` here to get the output you want:

```
$query = "date=20.10.2007&amount=400+date=11.02.2008&amount=1400+date=12.03.2008&amount=1500";
$array = explode("+", $query);  

$counter = 0;
echo "Date         Amount\n";
foreach($array as $item) {
    if ($counter > 0) echo "\n";
    $parts = explode("&", $item);
    echo preg_split("/=/", $parts[0])[1] . "   ";
    echo preg_split("/=/", $parts[1])[1];
    $counter = $counter + 1;
}
```

This prints:

```
Date         Amount
20.10.2007   400
11.02.2008   1400
12.03.2008   1500
```

The logic here is that we first split the query string on `+` to obtain components looking like:

```
date=20.10.2007&amount=400
```

Then, inside the loop over all such components, we split again by `&` to obtain the `date` and `amount` terms.  Finally, each of these are split again on `=` to get the actual values.

Comment: Thanks a lot for your kind guidance. from your help i did it with this code below:                                       $str = "date=20.10.2007&amount=400+date=11.02.2008&amount=1400+date=12.03.2008&amount=1500";
$array = explode("+",$str);
  $i = 0;
  echo nl2br("Date       Amount \n");
  foreach($array as $item[$i]) {
    parse_str($item[$i]);
echo $date;
echo $amount."<br>";
  $i++;
}

Answer (score 0):

Thanks a lot Tim Biegeleisen for your kind guidance. From your help i did it with this code below:

```
$str = "date=20.10.2007&amount=400+date=11.02.2008&amount=1400+date=12.03.2008&amount=1500"; $array = explode("+",$str); 
$i = 0; 
echo nl2br("Date Amount \n"); 
foreach($array as $item[$i]) 
{ 
parse_str($item[$i]); 
echo $date; 
echo $amount."<br>"; 
$i++;
 }
```